# how to join across mirrored edge 0

Tags: mirror

What is the method to join points across the mirror edge?

[image: merge at edge]

Comment: it's not possible, you need to apply your modifier

Comment: all I want to do is what Lile does in this tut at 7: 03. Is it just a matter of lining up to the edge then? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT1GNMevfc&t=579s

Comment: he doesn't create an edge between the 2 vertices, he just sticks the 2 vertices so that they're one, you need to activate the Clipping option of the Mirror modifier if you want to do it

Comment: 'Merge' on the mirror will do.. then scale the vertices you want to weld about your  mirror center, in the mirror direction, to 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an edge between a vertex and its mirrored image you need to apply the modifier. That said, if you want the 2 vertices to stick together (and merge into one unique when you'll apply the modifier), you need to activate the *Clipping* and the *Merge* options of the *Mirror* modifier.

Comment: AND the merge option.

Comment: oops you're right  ;)